# How to return Ctrl+M from ncurses getch()?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I am writing an application using ncurses and trying to get a CTRL-M keypress from the keyboard. Ncurses is returning CTRL-J (aka \n) whenever I press CTRL-M (aka \r), so I suspect somewhere it is doing a CRLF translation. My program is running in raw() mode so I don't think it should be doing any translation. Is this an ncurses problem or is it coming from somewhere upstrea, like the terminal driver?

How can I get it to give me raw key presses without translation?

FWIW I am using ncurses on Linux, running bash in xfce4-terminal. My TERM is xterm-256color. I've searched on Google and checked the ncurses docs but can't find anything on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`nonl()`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html). Although it is documented in the `outopts` manual section, it affects input as well.